# Import mail using doveadm import on a Hestia server setup

Tags: dovecot

I have a Hestia CP server running Dovecot. The mail lives in `/home/[username]/mail/[domain]/[account]`. I've copied the mail directory of the account I want to import into the `/tmp/` directory and now trying to figure out how `dovecotadm import` works so I can merge all those messages into the active mail account.

I've tried `doveadm import -u account@domain.tld maildir:/tmp/account/Maildir /home/username/mail/domain/account/Maildir all` - it doesn't give and error, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all. As with most things when I'm digging around in the commandline, it's probably just because I'm not familiar with the syntax. Could someone enlighten me?

The server is Ubuntu 18.04 with Hestia v1.6.10.

Cheers

Comment: What does `doveadm -vD import ...` say?